# How to configure OpenVPN client to use different DNS servers when connected

Tags: debian, openvpn, systemd-resolved

How to configure a Debian-based build with systemd, such that when connected to my VPN provider via an OpenVPN client, the system uses the DNS servers of the VPN provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went on quite a journey with this one, so I just wanted to capture my finding and a solution.

Apparently, the gold standard for configuring this in the past was a helper script called [update-systemd-resolved](https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved) but apparently, this has stopped working with recent versions of NetworkManager.

These are the steps I went through to set up the configuration that I wanted. (*This assumes you already have your OpenVPN client configured and connecting.*)

```bash
# Make a copy of any existing resolv.conf configuration
sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.original
# This sets resolvd to redirect to the systemd-resolve 127.0.0.53 redirect
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
# Edit the systemd-resolve configuration file
sudo vi /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
```

- Set `DNS=` to your local LAN/router DNS IP (i.e. 192.168.1.1)
- Set `Domains=` to your local LAN domain (i.e. my.company.com)

```bash
sudo service systemd-resolved restart
resolvectl status
```

The global entry should now reflect the values you set in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

```
Global
          Protocols: +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: stub
Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
        DNS Domain: my.company.com
```

Now create a helper script in the same directory your openvpn.client.conf file is
`/etc/openvpn` or `/etc/openvpn/client`

This is an example that I used for NordVPN

```bash
sudo vi /etc/openvpn/nordvpn.systemd.resolve.sh
# Make the script executable
sudo chmod 750 /etc/openvpn/nordvpn.systemd.resolve.sh
```

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
systemd-resolve -i tun0 \
  --set-dns=103.86.96.100 --set-dns=103.86.99.100 \
  --set-domain=~. \
  --set-dnssec=off
```

Now, modify your actual openvpn.client.conf file (*mine is named nordvpn.conf, but yours may be different*)

```bash
sudo vi /etc/openvpn/nordvpn.conf
```

...and add the following lines: (*using the name of the script you created above*)

```bash
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/nordvpn.systemd.resolve.sh
```

Now restart your OpenVPN client: *The service name may vary, depending on how you configured your OpenVPN client systemd service*

```bash
sudo systemctl restart openvpn@nordvpn.service
```

Confirm there were no errors during the restart:

```bash
sudo systemctl status openvpn@nordvpn.service
resolvectl status
```

The global entry should reflect the values you set in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and the tun interface should show the DNS values you added via your script

```
Global
          Protocols: +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: stub
Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
        DNS Domain: my.company.com

Link # (tun0)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 103.86.96.100
       DNS Servers: 103.86.96.100 103.86.99.100
        DNS Domain: ~.
```

Now, when you're connected to your VPN, you'll use the VPN provider's DNS servers, but when you're not connected, you'll revert back to your LAN DNS server.